# login with xdm and umlaut in password

Tags: login, locale, character-encoding, display-manager

I want use `xdm` to login to my machine and start my session. My password contains an umlaut. I'd rather not change the password as it is quite long and complex and I just memorized it.

Login works fine in `xdm` if there is no umlaut in password.
Login works fine if I login to shell directly with umlaut in password (I start my X Session from there currently).

So my assumption was that login in `xdm` should work fine with umlaut as well.

My `LANG` parameter is `de_DE.UTF-8`. I can become `root` on the machine.

If I type the Password in the username field of xdm it looks perfectly valid and displays the umlaut correctly. So, maybe its a `ISO-8859-15` vs. `UTF-8` problem, but I have no idea how to probe that.

Answer (score 2):

I went through HOWTO file in a *shadow* package and found out that many log in steps are handled by PAM nowadays. In `/etc/pam.d/login` file I found following snippet:

```
# This module parses environment configuration file(s)
# and also allows you to use an extended config
# file /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
# 
# parsing /etc/environment needs "readenv=1"
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
# locale variables are also kept into /etc/default/locale in etch
# reading this file *in addition to /etc/environment* does not hurt
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

My `/etc/default/locale` is something like this:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Currently I'm on Ubuntu, other distros might have other file names.

To be honest I'm not really sure if it's helpful; I also doubt that it's wise to have non-latin characters in password.